# Why does Swift default to double floating-point?

Tags: swift, type-inference

The [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399) says:

> `Double` represents a 64-bit floating-point number. Use it when
>   floating-point values must be very large or particularly precise.
>
> `Float` represents a 32-bit floating-point number. Use it when
>   floating-point values do not require 64-bit precision.

but then later on:

> Swift always chooses `Double` (rather than `Float`) when inferring the type of floating-point numbers.

Isn't this a bit of a contradiction? Won't 64-bit precision be excessive for *most* floating-point numbers? And does this mean that I should be explicit about defining Float numbers as such, or does the difference not really matter in practice?

Comment: Double is the best choice for scalar values for several reasons.  First, floats are really not very accurate - add 0.01 to a sum a million times and you'll get 9865.  Second, most modern processors are 64-bit, making it just as fast to move around a double as a float.  Third, CPU's use 80-bit registers to do their floating point math in either case - you're not making the computations any faster by using float.  For 3D gaming arrays of floats are still best though as they minimize memory usage while maximizing memory copy speeds and rendering speeds - and not all gfx cards support double.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defaulting to `Double` gives the guarantee that no floating-point precision errors will be caused by the type inference.

Defaulting to `Float` would cause troubles in some instances, so I'd say this is a conservative choice.

I've no hard numbers to support my claim, but I suspect this is also justified by the difference in performance not being so relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Why floating point numbers are inferred as `Double` could be due:

1) Many other languages like JAVA and Haskell infer floating point as `Double`

2) `Double`, with the higher precision, ensure that the precision is not lost. They have made the decision towards keeping the precision, over potential performance improvements (lower memory) that may be seen while using `Float`.